# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Politics's [first moderator election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: CDJB] [image: JJJ]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5688578731409408/0).

Comment: Congrats to @CDJB and @JJJ!

Comment: Y'all probably have one of the toughest jobs on the network especially for the next month or so on the US side. Good luck and congrats!

Comment: I see you 2 are already both hard at work deleting my comments.  Good job, carry on! 

Answer (score 17):

Wow, thank you to the community for your support, and especially to the other candidates for stepping up!

Congratulations also to JJJ, I'm looking forward to working with you and the rest of the moderation team! :)

Comment: Congratulations and best of luck! Take advantage of the Teachers Lounge... lots of wizened old mods there to offer perspective/advice.

Answer (score 9):

Bravo and Good Luck to the winners, CDJB & JJJ! The voters made capital choices!  (Or perhaps most voters are capitalists...)

Comment: Let's just say the voters made a *collective* effort. 

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for voting and participating, everyone! Congratulations CDJB, I'm looking forward to working with you and the moderation team as well.

As others have pointed out, these are going to be some interesting times. With this team and the vigilant community at large, I'm sure we can take on the challenge and maybe even grow our userbase along the way.

Comment: Congrats and best of luck with moderation!

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations to all candidates. An election can be a stressful process, and you have all handled it wonderfully.

CDJB and JJJ, welcome to the team!

Answer (score 5):

Congrats to both of you, CDJB and JJJ! I'm very confident the two of you will both make really good moderators. Thanks for helping keep the site clean.